Proper Kotlin declaration of Generics for higher-order functions
I currently have a situation where I have a couple of data classes (Script and FreeScript) that I want to handle in the same fashion in some code what walks a dataset. For example:
fun toScripts(parseScript: () -> (Script)): List<Script> {
    val result: MutableList<Script> = mutableListOf()
    while (findNextTag("tr") != null) {
        result.add(parseScript(elementsContainer))
    }
    return result
}

fun toFreeScripts(parseFreeScript: () -> (FreeScript)): List<FreeScript> {
    val result: MutableList<FreeScript> = mutableListOf()
    while (findNextTag("tr") != null) {
        result.add(parseFreeScript(elementsContainer))
    }
    return result
}

The only difference between these methods is that they take a function that produces a different result type, and construct a list of that result type. This seems like a good candidate for use of Generics, but I can't seem to some up with the proper declaration syntax.
What can I try to resolve this?

What did you try so far? I mean, yes, you are correct, this is a perfect example for generics. But this is also the most basic example, which you should be able to do by simply reading the documentation and adapting examples there. What is the part which is the most confusing to you? What didn't work in your attempts?

I tried various combinations of () -> () and () ->  but couldn't seem to get anything to work.

Please look at the very first example in docs: fun <T> singletonList(item: T): List<T>. They use just T in params and return type.

Yep, just what was needed. Thanks.

If you solved your problem, please add an answer with the solution :-)

Thanks to @broot for a nudge in the right direction. The proper declaration is:
fun <T> toScripts(parseScript: () -> T): List<T> {
    val result: MutableList<T> = mutableListOf()
    while (findNextTag("tr") != null) {
        result.add(parseScript(elementsContainer))
    }
    return result
}

